# Dead Simple Java IO & Enum Question

Tags: java, enums, io

I know there is something dead simple I'm missing, but the following code won't write the text using `println`:

```
import java.io.*;   
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ConfigureSettings{   
    private PrintWriter SettingsFile;   
    private enum Dodge{   
        Ascending, Descending, Off  
    };   
    private enum Damage{   
        Ascending, Descending, Off   
    };   
    private enum DPS{   
        Ascending, Descending, Off   
    };   

    ConfigureSettings(){
        try{
            SettingsFile = new PrintWriter(new File("UserSettings"));
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry cannot open UserSettings File");
        }
        SettingsFile.println("k");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new ConfigureSettings();
    }
}
```

My Enumeration question is can I create an Enumeration of Enumeration's? I mean can I wrap the three current enum variables I have, Dodge Damage and DPS, in Super enum class?

P.S. I know my code isn't displaying correctly, any hints for future posts/edits?

Comment: concerning the code formatting: You need to indent code blocks with 4 spaces, then it'll display correctly. Take a look at the [Markdown formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning the **missing `println` output**: Have you tried `flush`ing the `PrintWriter` after `println`, and explicitly `close`ing it when you no longer need it?

As to your **enum of enums question** — what would an enum of enums be good for? Do you mean something like this (which I just made up — I'm quite sure it won't compile):

```
private enum Enumenum {
    enum Dodge {
        Ascending, Descending, Off
    },
    enum Damage {
    Ascending, Descending, Off
    },
    enum DPS {
        Ascending, Descending, Off
    }
}
```

What would you do with such a complicated enum? Why not simply:

```
    enum OneForAll {
        Ascending, Descending, Off
    }
```

And then use this enum instead of the other three, since they all contain the same enumeration values anyway?

(Update: Note however that using the same enum instead of three separate enums might very well reduce the type safety of your code, so the above suggestion might not necessarily be a good thing.)

Comment: Using one enum like `OneForAll` would break the typesafety for enums that the `enum` keyword was meant to add to Java.

Comment: @rsp, you're correct about reduced type safety. (On the other hand, creating an enum of enums doesn't seem so much better in that regard: If you want three enums that don't get mixed up, type safety-wise, you probably shouldn't try "fusing" them into one super-enum.)

Comment: wow cheers I simply flushed then closed the printwriter object and it fixed my problem. Can you explain why though? So that I won't make a similar mistake.

Comment: @Malaken: Remember that I/O operations are usually expensive. For this reason, all output to files is usually buffered by the operating system to improve performance. `flush` tells the OS to commit the buffer contents to disk. Before that, especially if the buffer is not full and the system hasn't been idle for some time, the buffer is *not* written to disk -- that's why you didn't see your output. But I can't tell you why your output was not written at all. But then it doesn't hurt to *always* at least close your files explicitly, e.g. in a `try..finally` block.